# How to get a list of titles and summaries from the Wikipedia API?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I've been trying to get a list of possible results (same you would get as you perform a search in Wikipedia) and a small summary of the article, usually the first paragraph.

So far all I can get is either the list of titles:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&origin=*&list=search&srprop&srsearch=Albert%20Einstein&prop=extracts

or the summary for a single page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Albert%20Einstein

Is it possible to combine both these queries in a form similar to this

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&origin=*&list=search&srprop&srsearch=Albert%20Einstein&prop=extracts

or will I have to iterate all results from the first query and then get the extract for each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the results from two or more queries by using [generator parameter](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Generators). So the idea is to [generate](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query) a list of [search](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bsearch) results (your first query) including [extracts](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bextracts) property for each one result (your second query):

```
action=query&generator=search&prop=extracts
```

Then we need to add some parameters for generator (all they prefixed with a "g")

```
gsrsearch=Albert%20Einstein&gsrlimit=20
```

and parameters for all query properties (in our case only for extracts):

```
exintro=1&explaintext=1&exchars=250&exlimit=20
```

The final query will be:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&origin=*&generator=search&prop=extracts&gsrsearch=Albert%20Einstein&gsrlimit=20&exintro=1&explaintext=1&exchars=350&exlimit=20
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! How would I go about adding a second prop (url) to the query? Simply appending &url after prop=extracts doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Danyx to add another properties you have to separate them by pipe "|", like: `prop=categories|extracts|images|...`

Comment: How can we get the list of all links available in the 'See Also' section?

Comment: @Abhishek See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40210536/how-to-obtain-data-in-a-table-from-wikipedia-api/40388912#40388912) can to access content of some section.