# How to obtain data in a table from Wikipedia API?

Tags: api, mediawiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to get all the content from [Wikipedia:Unusual_articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Unusual_articles) and I'm able to get the list of table content by calling this endpoint:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=sections&page=Wikipedia:Unusual_articles
```

and the data I got back look something like this:

```
{
    title: "Wikipedia:Unusual articles",
    pageid: 154126,
    sections: [
        {
            toclevel: 1,
            level: "2",
            line: "Places and infrastructure",
            number: "1",
            index: "T-1",
            fromtitle: "Wikipedia:Unusual_articles/Places_and_infrastructure",
            byteoffset: null,
            anchor: "Places_and_infrastructure"
        },
        {
            toclevel: 2,
            level: "3",
            line: "Americas",
            number: "1.1",
            index: "T-2",
            fromtitle: "Wikipedia:Unusual_articles/Places_and_infrastructure",
            byteoffset: null,
            anchor: "Americas"
        },
...
```

But I'm not able to get the content of a particular section. For example under `Americas` is a list of the table with a link and a short description, but is there a way to obtain the link and short description from the API?

[image: table]

Comment: I'd suggest reading the API documentation and figuring out which API call will give you article content.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to parse the table HTML. The API call is almost right, your are just using the wrong property.

Comment: @Tgr what props am I supposed to use to get the table html?

Comment: Try [this query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=parse&format=json&page=Wikipedia%3AUnusual_articles%2FPlaces_and_infrastructure&prop=text&section=2) (the table is transcluded from a subpage). In general, ApiSandbox is the easy way to find out what parameters you need.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get the content of every page section by using MediaWiki API with [action=parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=parse) in two steps. First you have to get all sections from the page with:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&prop=sections&page=Wikipedia:Unusual_articles
```

From the response you see that section `Americas` has **index=**`T-2` (**T** means transcluded page) and it comes from **fromtitle=**`Wikipedia:Unusual_articles/Places_and_infrastructure`. Now we use these **index** and **fromtitle** to get the content of the section with:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Wikipedia:Unusual_articles/Places_and_infrastructure&section=2&prop=...
```

where:

- `prop=wikitext` - gives the original section wikitext that was parsed.
- `prop=text` - gives the parsed section text of the wikitext.

Comment: i'm able to get section details from above api. by passing section index.
but it returning html text . I want to get only plain text. how can i get it ?